# Rank with group

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table1 like this

```
Dept    Class   Dept1   Class1      date
NULL    NULL     a      history     02-2020
NULL    NULL     a      bio         02-2020
a       math    NULL    NULL        02-2020
a       chemi   NULL    NULL        02-2020
a       history NULL    NULL        02-2020
b       PE      NULL    NULL        03-2020
b       Music   NULL    NULL        03-2020
b       Sport   NULL    NULL        03-2020
NULL    NULL     b      Cook        03-2020
c       Psy     NULL    NULL        04-2020
```

Can we query that look like this

```
Dept    Class   Dept1   Class1      date
a       math     a      history     02-2020
a       chemi    a      bio         02-2020
a       history NULL    NULL        02-2020
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL        02-2020
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL        02-2020
b       PE      b       Cook        03-2020
b       Music   NULL    NULL        03-2020
b       Sport   NULL    NULL        03-2020
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL        03-2020
c       Psy     NULL    NULL        04-2020
```

The goal try to get records group by Dept, Dept1 and date 
you can use any fields with nvarchar or interger  
My query and not working well

```
select coalesce(sm.dept, su.dept1) as dept,
               sm.class,
               su.class1,
               sm.date
        from 
                (select distinct w.*, 
                 row_number() over (partition by dept order by [date] asc) as seqnum
                 from table1 w
                 ) sm
          full join
                 (select w.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by dept1 order by [date] asc) as seqnum
                  from table1 w

                 ) su

         on sm.dept = su.dept1 and sm.seqnum = su.seqnum
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes . . . you seem to want the columns in "groups" aligned by date.  Here is one method:

```
select date, max(dept), max(class), max(dept1), max(class1)
from ((select date, row_number() over (order by dept) as seqnum,
              dept, null as class, null as dept1, null as class1
       from t
       where dept is not null
      ) union all
      (select date, row_number() over (order by class) as seqnum,
              null as dept, class, null as dept1, null as class1
       from t
       where class is not null
      ) union all
      (select date, row_number() over (order by dept1) as seqnum,
              null, null as class, dept1, null as class1
       from t
       where dept1 is not null
      ) union all
      (select date, row_number() over (order by class1) as seqnum,
              null as dept, null as class, null as dept1, class1
       from t
       where class1 is not null
      )
     ) x
group by date, seqnum;
```

Comment: @user13636604 . . . No.  That is handled by `seqnum`.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to order by date and then order by dept, class, dept1, class1 columns. In SQL Server, by default NULL appears at the top. So, I am replacing NULL values with ZZZZZ to make them come in the end. you can replace ZZZZZ with big varchar field, which will not be coming in your dept, class, dept1, class1 fields.

```sql
DECLARE @dept table(dept varchar(50),class varchar(50),dept1 varchar(50),class1 varchar(50),datev varchar(50))

insert into @dept VALUES
(NULL    ,NULL        ,'a'     ,'history'    ,'02-2020')
,(NULL    ,NULL        ,'a'    , 'bio'        ,'02-2020')
,('a'       ,'math'    ,NULL   , NULL        ,'02-2020')
,('a'       ,'chemi'   ,NULL   , NULL        ,'02-2020')
,(null       ,NULL   ,NULL   , NULL        ,'02-2020')
,(null       ,NULL   ,NULL   , NULL        ,'02-2020')
,('a'       ,'history' ,NULL   , NULL        ,'02-2020')
,('b'       ,'PE'      ,NULL   , NULL        ,'03-2020')
,('b'       ,'Music'   ,NULL   , NULL        ,'03-2020')
,('b'       ,'Sport'   ,NULL   , NULL        ,'03-2020')
,(NULL    ,NULL        ,'b'     ,'Cook'        ,'03-2020')
,(null       ,NULL   ,NULL   , NULL        ,'03-2020')
,('c'       ,'Psy'     ,NULL    ,NULL        ,'04-2020');

SELECT  DEPT, class, dept1, class1, datev 
from
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by datev,isnull(dept,'ZZZZZ'),isnull(class,'ZZZZZ'),isnull(dept1,'ZZZZZ'),isnull(class1,'ZZZZZ') ) as rnk FROM @dept
) AS T
order by rnk
```

```
+------+---------+-------+---------+---------+
| DEPT |  class  | dept1 | class1  |  datev  |
+------+---------+-------+---------+---------+
| a    | chemi   | NULL  | NULL    | 02-2020 |
| a    | history | NULL  | NULL    | 02-2020 |
| a    | math    | NULL  | NULL    | 02-2020 |
| NULL | NULL    | a     | bio     | 02-2020 |
| NULL | NULL    | a     | history | 02-2020 |
| NULL | NULL    | NULL  | NULL    | 02-2020 |
| NULL | NULL    | NULL  | NULL    | 02-2020 |
| b    | Music   | NULL  | NULL    | 03-2020 |
| b    | PE      | NULL  | NULL    | 03-2020 |
| b    | Sport   | NULL  | NULL    | 03-2020 |
| NULL | NULL    | b     | Cook    | 03-2020 |
| NULL | NULL    | NULL  | NULL    | 03-2020 |
| c    | Psy     | NULL  | NULL    | 04-2020 |
+------+---------+-------+---------+---------+
```